# Find value that occurs twice

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
[{
      id: 'foo',
      name: 'apple',
      type: 'fruit'
    },
    {
      id: 'bar',
      name: 'banana',
      type: 'fruit'
    },
    { id:'baz',
      name: 'carrot',
      type: 'vegetable'
    }
  ];
```

I'm trying to figure out which type has occurred twice. E.g. in this case, fruit would appear twice in this object.

I've setup this code so far but it just results in the values occurring once and not twice and I'm not sure why.

Attempt:

```
let map = new Map();

for(let i=0; i < obj.length; i++){
  if(map.hasOwnProperty(obj[i].type))
  {
    map.set(obj[i].type, map.get(obj[i].type) +1);
  }
  else
  {
    map.set(obj[i].type, 1);
  }
}

let keys = Object.keys(map).filter(k=>map[k] === 2);
```

Where obj is the object above. keys returns an empty array and map just maps the types above to 1.

Not sure why it's not properly counting the occurrence.

Comment: Do you need like this? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/VwvmBWy

Answer (score 1):

You need to use proper [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) methods

- To get keys you need to use [`Map.prototype.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys)
- To check existence use [`Map.protoype.has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has)

```js
let obj = [{id: 'foo',name: 'apple',type: 'fruit'},{id: 'bar',name: 'banana',type: 'fruit'},{id: 'baz',name: 'carrot',type: 'vegetable'}];

let map = new Map();

for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  let key = obj[i].type
  if (map.has(key)) {
    map.set(key, map.get(key) + 1);
  } else {
    map.set(key, 1);
  }
}

let keys = [...map.keys()].filter(k => map.get(k) === 2);

console.log(keys)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @Code Maniac has answered your question correctly. You're using `hasOwnProperty` instead of `Map.has` and `map[k]` instead of `map.get(k).

Adding to that, the reason your code returns `Map {"fruit" => 1, "vegetable" => 1}` is because `hasOwnProperty` is not a `Map` method, but an `Object` method which checks whether a property with the key exists in that object or not. In your case, since you're adding to the map, using `Map.set`, it isn't added an Object property, which means the `if` condition is always returning false, making your code over-write the value in the `Map`.

If you want to use `hasOwnProperty`, you will need to change your `map` to a regular `Object`, instead of a `Map`. *(I mean, you can likely use `Map` as a regular `Object` as well, but that's just because JS is very flexible. Not recommended)*

```
let obj = [{id: 'foo',name: 'apple',type: 'fruit'},{id: 'bar',name: 'banana',type: 'fruit'},{id: 'baz',name: 'carrot',type: 'vegetable'}];

let map = {};

for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  if (map.hasOwnProperty(obj[i].type)) {
    map[obj[i].type] = map[obj[i].type] + 1;
  } else {
    map[obj[i].type] = 1;
  }
}

let keys = Object.keys(map).filter(k=>map[k] === 2);

console.log(keys)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your map as an object, then you would have to change a few things as `new Map()` does not create an object literal. Also, an object does not have `set` and `get`, so you cannot mix match functions from objects and the `Map` object. See [Objects_vs._Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_vs._Maps)

```js
let obj = [{
    id: "foo",
    name: "apple",
    type: "fruit",
  },
  {
    id: "bar",
    name: "banana",
    type: "fruit",
  },
  {
    id: "baz",
    name: "carrot",
    type: "vegetable"
  },
];

let map = {};

for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  if (map.hasOwnProperty(obj[i].type)) {
    map[obj[i].type] = map[obj[i].type] + 1;
  } else {
    map[obj[i].type] = 1;
  }
}

let keys = Object.keys(map).filter((k) => map[k] === 2);

console.log(keys)
```